# when I execute Linux split file command from Python , Files got split, but data being trucated

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to execute Linux file Split command based on number of lines from Python. Below is the code

```
cmd = 'split -a 4 --verbose --lines 1000 --additional-suffix=.csv master.csv split_file_'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

p.stdin.close()
print "Stdout:", p.stdout.read()
print "Stderr:", p.stderr.read()
```

When I try to execute the command in Linux directly I am getting files generated correctly.
But when executed from Python I am having issue.

Let say I have 2001 records in master.csv I am getting 2 files generated with 1000 lines in one file and 756 lines in another file. even the data in last line in second file is truncated.

Let say I have 1001 records in master.csv I am getting 1 file generated with 756  lines in one file even the data in last line is truncated.

I am using python2.7

Comment: The real bug here is that `Popen` merely _starts_ the command, but you are not allowing it to finish. You want to prefer `subprocess.check.output` if you really want to capture its output, or `subprocess.check_call`. Going forward, avoid `Popen` always when you can, and tangentially, probably try to migrate to Python 3 ASAP.

Comment: That should maybe be clarified to advice to avoid _bare_ `Popen` in favor of higher-level tools that wrap it, like `subprocess.run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of Struggles and googling I manage to fix the issue.

My Implementation was just to execute .py file from linux command line
So when executing directly .py file linux command (split) inside .py failed/partially executed.

So inorder to solve the issue, I moved split file command to shell script and then called py files from shell script only.

```
#!/bin/bash
python pythonfile1.py
split -a 4 --verbose --lines 50000 --additional-suffix=.csv csvfiles/master.csv csvfiles/split/split_file_
python pythonfile1.py
```

Not a perfect solution for actual issue but just a alternative to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Popen has a maximum buffer size. It can be adjusted with `bufsize` but it isn't recommended.

You would be better off writing the files to disk and reading them into your script or implementing the split function yourself in python

Comment: Still confused with Bufsize. If that is the problem then it should always return same result when I have 2001 records or 1001 records or 3001. But for me its only truncating in last file.

Comment: I tied to add bufsize also still same results

Comment: Then do the split in python. Every time you exec an external command from python, God kills a kitten.

Comment: This would one solution, but would include lot of complexity. But anyhow thanks for you help.